# Can LIBSVM handle 2D input features data for regression?

Tags: matlab, regression, libsvm

Lets say I have 2 input features and each input features have 2 independent variables (2D data), eg: T1(x,y) and T2(x+1,y), I wish to use LIBSVM for regression to predict T(x+1,y) (2D output data). I read through the official link but I would not be able to find whether the input data sets support two-dimensional data for both input features T1(x,y) and T2(x+1,y). Generally, I knew the LIBSVM supports T1(x) and T2(x+1) (1D data) but not sure whether it supports 2D data for each input features. Can libsvm support for this?

Answer (score 0):

For 2D feature, the simplest way is to split its rows and concatenate them into a single row.

Suppose your feature is like

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

transform it into

```
1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9
```

It just a way, you can search for "data preprocessing" for more information.